# sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6: not found

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I am facing issue while using sbt-assembly to build my jar. I have gone through almost all the post available but it did not help resolve my issue.

Below is my build.sbt -

```
name := "test"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
sbtVersion := "1.3.6"
```

assembly.sbt -

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

plugins.sbt -

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.6 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.6 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
```

During initial build, it is not downloading below files -

```
https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.14.6/ivys/ivy.xml
NaN% [          ] 0 B (0 B / s)
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.14.6/ivys/ivy.xml
NaN% [          ] 0 B (0 B / s)
```

and at the end it says [error] not found:

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.12_1.0/0.14.6/sbt-assembly-0.14.6.pom
```

`ivy.xml` files exists in given path but the `repo1.maven.org` path does not exists.
Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: you should not use http anymore nowadays.The plugin is there: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.14.6/ -- no need to define / override the plugin resolver...

Comment: i tried without defining plugin resolver but still got the same issue. For time being, i manually downloaded them into .ivy folder first and built my jar. Not sure why it is not working otherwise though.

Comment: could you create a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: BTW: `sbtVersion` - Provides the version of sbt.  *This setting should not be modified.* You should change the SBT version in `project/build.properties`.

Comment: yes i tried it without sbtVersion in build.sbt as well but same error. build.properties is pointing to 1.3.6 version.